# Prove Convolution is Equivariant with respect to translation

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning

I was reading the following statement about how convolution is equivariant with respect to translation from the Deep Learning Book.

> Let *g* be a function mapping one image function to another image
>   function, such that *I'=g(I)* is the image function with *I'(x, y)
>   =I(x−1, y)*. This shifts every pixel ofIone unit to the right. If we apply this transformation to *I*, then apply convolution, **the result will
>   be the same as if we applied convolution to *I'*, then applied the
>   transformation *g* to the output**.

For the last line I bolded, they are applying convolution to *I'*, but shouldn't this be *I*? *I'* is the translated image. Otherwise it would effectively be saying:

```
f(g(I)) = g( f(g(I)) )
```

where *f* is convolution & *g* is translation. 
I am trying to execute the same myself in python using 3D kernel equal to the depth of the image as would be the case in the convolution layer for a colored image, a house.

[image: Input colored image]

Here is my code for applying a translation & then convolution to an image.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np
import scipy
import scipy.ndimage

I = scipy.ndimage.imread('pics/house.jpg')

def convolution(A, B):
    return np.sum( np.multiply(A, B) )

k = np.array([[[0,1,-1],[1,-1,0],[0,0,0]], [[-1,0,-1],[1,-1,0],[1,0,0]], [[1,-1,0],[1,0,1],[-1,0,1]]]) #kernel


## Translation
translated = 100
new_I = np.zeros( (I.shape[0]-translated, I.shape[1], I.shape[2]) )

for i in range(translated, I.shape[0]):
    for j in range(I.shape[1]):
        for l in range(I.shape[2]):
            new_I[i-translated,j,l] = I[i,j,l]

## Convolution
conv = np.zeros( (int((new_I.shape[0]-3)/2), int((new_I.shape[1]-3)/2) ) )

for i in range( conv.shape[0] ):
    for j in range(conv.shape[1]):
        conv[i, j] = convolution(new_I[2*i:2*i+3, 2*j:2*j+3, :], k)


scipy.misc.imsave('pics/convoled_image_2nd.png', conv)
```

I get the following output:

[image: Translated then Convolved]

Now, I switch the convolution and Translation steps:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np
import scipy
import scipy.ndimage

I = scipy.ndimage.imread('pics/house.jpg')

def convolution(A, B):
    return np.sum( np.multiply(A, B) )

k = np.array([[[0,1,-1],[1,-1,0],[0,0,0]], [[-1,0,-1],[1,-1,0],[1,0,0]], [[1,-1,0],[1,0,1],[-1,0,1]]]) #kernel


## Convolution
conv = np.zeros( (int((I.shape[0]-3)/2), int((I.shape[1]-3)/2) ) )

for i in range( conv.shape[0] ):
    for j in range(conv.shape[1]):
        conv[i, j] = convolution(I[2*i:2*i+3, 2*j:2*j+3, :], k)


## Translation
translated = 100
new_I = np.zeros( (conv.shape[0]-translated, conv.shape[1]) )

for i in range(translated, conv.shape[0]):
    for j in range(conv.shape[1]):
        new_I[i-translated,j] = conv[i,j]


scipy.misc.imsave('pics/conv_trans_image.png', new_I)
```

And now I get the following output:

[image: First Convolved with kernel & then translated]

Shouldn't they be the same according the book? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: FWIW, you should probably convert those `## Translation` and `## Convolution` blocks into functions `translation` and `convolution`. Then it's easy for a reader to verify `translation(convolution(I))` vs `convolution(translation(I))` without having to compare line-by-line.

Comment: Also, what's the difference between your two images?

Comment: One image is cropped at the top, the other is not. They are different sizes too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as the book says, the linearity properties of convolution and translation guarantee that their order is interchangable, excepting boundary effects.

For instance:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import misc, ndimage, signal

def translate(img, dx):
    img_t = np.zeros_like(img)
    if dx == 0:  img_t[:, :]   = img[:, :]
    elif dx > 0: img_t[:, dx:] = img[:, :-dx]
    else:        img_t[:, :dx] = img[:, -dx:]
    return img_t

def convolution(img, k):
    return np.sum([signal.convolve2d(img[:, :, c], k[:, :, c])
        for c in range(img.shape[2])], axis=0)

img = ndimage.imread('house.jpg')

k = np.array([
    [[ 0,  1, -1], [1, -1, 0], [ 0, 0, 0]],
    [[-1,  0, -1], [1, -1, 0], [ 1, 0, 0]],
    [[ 1, -1,  0], [1,  0, 1], [-1, 0, 1]]])

ct = translate(convolution(img, k), 100)
tc = convolution(translate(img, 100), k)

misc.imsave('conv_then_trans.png', ct)
misc.imsave('trans_then_conv.png', tc)

if np.all(ct[2:-2, 2:-2] == tc[2:-2, 2:-2]):
    print('Equal!')
```

Prints:

> Equal!

---

The problem is that you're overtranslating in the second example. After you shrink the image 2x, try translating by **`50`** instead.